# perror: No such file or directory

Tags: c, fwrite, temp, assertion

I have function. FA->file_temp is a copy of FA->file. FA->file_temp is being in TEMP dir. (C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp)

```
stat(FA->file, &st_file);
filesize = st_file.st_size;
ffile = fopen(FA->file_temp, "rb");
if (ffile == NULL) perror("NULL!!!!!!!!!!!!!1\n");

strcpy(str, FA->file_dir);
strcat(str, "packed");
temp_name(str) ;
strcpy( FA->tmpname , str);
ftmpname = fopen(FA->tmpname, "wb");
if (ftmpname == NULL) perror("NULL!!!!!!!!!!!!!1\n");
 if (rc = encode(ffile, ftmpname, filesize)!=0) 
     longjmp(Berror, rc);
```

Answer (score 1):

Perchance, does your program yell `'NULL!!!!!!!!!!!!'` before  `assertion failed`? The message  about the assertion is saying that `fo` is null.

While I'm here,

```
if (rc = encode(ffile, ftmpname, filesize)!=0)
```

Is probably not what you want. This stores all of `encode(ffile, ftmpname, filesize)!=0` into `rc`. You probably meant:

```
if ((rc = encode(ffile, ftmpname, filesize))!=0)
```

Comment: @sleepy, putting an assignment inside an `if` condition is one of the worst of ideas anyhow. The common idiom is to put the assignment before the `if` and then simply do `if (rc) `.